# When a sacrifice calls for "two turtledoves or two common doves", can it be one of each?

Tags: korban, animals, beis-hamikdash

There are places in the Torah that call for an offering of "two turtledoves, or two common doves" (as translated by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan), e.g. [Leviticus 12:8](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=3&CHAPTER=12).

Could s/he bring one of each kind, instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mishnah Kinnim 2:6:

> אין מביאין תורין כנגד בני יונה, ולא בני יונה כנגד תורין.  כיצד:  האישה שהביאה חטאתה תור, ועולתה בן יונה--תכפול, ותביא עולתה תור.  עולתה תור, וחטאתה בן יונה--תכפול, ותביא עולתה בן יונה.  בן עזאי אומר, הולכין אחר ראשון

Comment: Sifra (Dibura DeChatas 18:3, explaining Lev. 5:7) also says שממין חטאת תבא עולה, and Rambam cites this as halachah (Hil. Pesulei Hamukdashin 10:1).